# Restricted login access wp?

Tags: wordpress

I want to restricted my login access on wordpress. User can login only through `http://wp.com/admin-login`. Except (ie. wp-admin/wp-login.php/whatever), user will redirect to homepage. How to make it?
Thank you.

Comment: The question is a little unclear, but it looks like it might have been a better git on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, as it's not immediately obvious that it has anything to do with programming. It looks like it's more about Wordpress administration, maybe even server administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/ activate it under that plugin there is a tab hide you can change to the desire login as you like. hope this will be useful for you and u can gain more security through here :)

Comment: you can vote on .. y only on the comment still you can accept the answer :).. haha anyway its my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the filesystem, you could use a `.htaccess` file to prevent users except from a certain ip address or site. You have to keep the `.htaccess` file in the folder to which you want to prevent access.

First off, create a blank file called `.htaccess` and make sure you save it in the 'All Files' filetype (if using notepad on windows).

Put the following into the file:

```
order allow, deny
deny from all
allow your-ip-address-here
```

Save the file and put it in the appropriate folder. Now you can access the folder only from your-ip-address-here.

If you try to access the folder from anywhere else, the server will give a `403 Forbidden` error. If you place the `.htaccess` file in the root of your filesystem, then the entire site will be accessible from only that ip.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress as it sits is not that secure. I know personally, I manage 10+ sites and they're constantly getting hit by rogue servers from all over the world. (like this lovely individual from Korea http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/1.234.83.77)

I'd HIGHLY recommend http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/ . You don't need to roll your own security, use what they provide, and hey, if you like it go pro! I'm not at all related to the company, but i've had A LOT of success with their plugins.

Follow all of the steps, lock everything down, fix your file permissions and cross your fingers. If someone wants to get in, they'll find a way. You can only attempt to mitigate all risk.

Additionally if you're on your own linux virtual host (rackspace/amazon/etc), I'd recommend linux ufw.

```
sudo aptitude install ufw 
sudo ufw allow 80
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 443
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

One final suggestion fail2ban is an excellent resource, not for wordpress direct, but for any logins to your server. It will lock out individuals similar to Better WP Security.

Best of luck, let us know what you decide!